# Can IntelliJ be made to use the Grails wrapper?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Using the [Grails wrapper](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/wrapper.html) (grailsw) downloads the right Grails distribution to your .grails folder if you don't already have it. So:

- svn co myproject .
- <strike>grails run-app (first get correct Grails distro and tell Intellij, or set GRAILS_HOME)</strike>
- grailsw run-app (it just works)

Question is: can IntelliJ be configured to use grailsw when running grails commands?

Comment: What version of intellij idea do you use? and wht do you mean by your question: run grails app by clicking green run button?

Comment: I would think he means all grails command line executions IntelliJ does. Like run, "synchronize grails settings", creating domain classes, controllers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run > Edit Configurations > Add > Bash and then point "Script" to grailsw and adjust working directory.